# Kafka Docker - Can't produce or consume from outside of docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, spotify, apache-zookeeper

Kafka works fine in the docker container. I can use `docker exec -it [container name] [kafkascript]` and successfully create topics, produce/consume messages, but when I try from outside of the docker container using local kafka scripts I can only create and list topics.  Producing and consuming messages throws errors:

**Producing**:

`~/development/lib/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list $(docker-machine ip kafka):9092 --topic test
asdf`

```
[2016-09-18 10:13:48,999] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test-0
```

**Consuming:**

`~/development/lib/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper $(docker-machine ip kafka):2181 --topic test --from-beginning`

```
[2016-09-18 09:57:10,389] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(test)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,ba762186182f,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:80)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
[2016-09-18 09:57:10,392] WARN [console-consumer-34526_3c15c2c24040-1474210630122-9404562b-leader-finder-thread], Failed to find leader for Set([test,0]) (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(test)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(BrokerEndPoint(0,ba762186182f,9092))] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:73)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:80)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
    ... 3 more
```

I'm using spotify/docker-kafka ,but I upgraded it to 0.10.0.0 and used some suggestions from [jshark](https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka/issues/40) that sets up advertised.listeners. I'm running on a Mac. I've created a docker-machine called kafka. Here is my docker run:

```
 docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip kafka` --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 kafka
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
# Kafka and Zookeeper

FROM java:openjdk-8-jre

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.11
ENV KAFKA_VERSION 0.10.0.0
ENV KAFKA_HOME /opt/kafka_"$SCALA_VERSION"-"$KAFKA_VERSION"

# Install Kafka, Zookeeper and other needed things
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y zookeeper wget supervisor dnsutils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get clean && \
    wget -q http://apache.mirrors.spacedump.net/kafka/"$KAFKA_VERSION"/kafka_"$SCALA_VERSION"-"$KAFKA_VERSION".tgz -O /tmp/kafka_"$SCALA_VERSION"-"$KAFKA_VERSION".tgz && \
    tar xfz /tmp/kafka_"$SCALA_VERSION"-"$KAFKA_VERSION".tgz -C /opt && \
    rm /tmp/kafka_"$SCALA_VERSION"-"$KAFKA_VERSION".tgz

ADD scripts/start-kafka.sh /usr/bin/start-kafka.sh

# Supervisor config
ADD supervisor/kafka.conf supervisor/zookeeper.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

# 2181 is zookeeper, 9092 is kafka
EXPOSE 2181
EXPOSE 9092

CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

[scripts/start-kafka.sh](https://gist.github.com/JonathanAaron/0f21bcbefbda26e41e29d560ef97e48a)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37655203/1839580

My summary: The `ADVERTISED_HOST` environment variable in the `spotify/kafka` container needs to change depending on whether your service is operating inside or outside the container.  I an using Docker for Mac and I have my docker network set to bridged.  Outside of Docker the `ADVERTISED_HOST` needed to be set to localhost, inside of docker, it was set to `myproject_kafka_1` or whatever it ends up being on your system.  To fix it, I added and entry in my MacOS host files that mapped `127.0.0.1` to `myproject_kafka_1`.  I don't like messing with my host file, but it fixed this issue for me.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   myproject_kafka_1
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to interact with Kafka from outside its container until I added the following entries to server.properties:

```
listener.security.protocol.map=INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT

advertised.listeners=INSIDE://${container_ip}:9092,OUTSIDE://${outside_host_ip}:29092

listeners=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:29092

inter.broker.listener.name=INSIDE
```

I posted a more complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55649654/4828060). Hope others won't spend as much time on this as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner would be to set `advertised.listeners=host-ip:port` since `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port` are deprecated in Kafka `server.properties` file.

If set `host-ip` to `0.0.0.0` it will listen requests from anywhere. But it's insecure.